# ¿Por qué se le pone const a un puntero a cadena de caracteres y no a un arreglo en c++?

Tags: c++, array, string, punteros, constantes

Al crear un arreglo de caracteres no tengo que ponerle const para que sea válido

```
char str[11] = "Hola Mundo";
```

En cambio cuando lo creo con puntero tengo que hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
const char* str = "Hola Mundo";
```

Tengo entendido que es por que una cadena literal es constante y por ello debo crear un const char para que el literal no pueda ser alterado. Sin embargo, no entiendo por que no sucede lo mismo con un arreglo, puedo crearlo sin anteponer const e inclusive tengo la posibilidad de modificar el literal asignado.

Answer (score 3):

Hay que tener presente que, en **ambos** casos, el texto `"Hola Mundo"` es **un literal**, y, como tal, el lenguaje indica que es **de solo lectura**: cualquier intento de modificar un literal es un **comportamiento indefinido**.

- En el primer caso

  char str[11] = "Hola Mundo";

estás creando **una variable con espacio suficiente** para contener toda la cadena literal. Y dicho literal **se copia** a la variable.

Por lo tanto, luego puedes modificarla sin ningún problema: estás modificando **la copia**, no la cadena original.

- En el segundo caso:

  const char* str = "Hola Mundo";

estás creando **un puntero** que *apuntará* a la dirección en memoria del literal `"Hola Mundo"`. Cualquier intento de modificar la cadena ... estás realmente modificando **el literal**. Y eso es un *comportamiento indefinido*.

Comment: Entonces cuando creo un puntero a una cadena literal ese puntero apunta a una dirección del code segment? @Trauma

Comment: Dependerá **del compilador**. Dudo mucho que un microcontrolador `Arduino` tenga nada parecido a un `code segment`.

Comment: Por eso mismo, el intentar modificarlo es un **comportamiento indefinido**. Existaran plataformas en las que se pueda. Y existirán plataformas en las que no pase nada. Y existirán plataformas en las que provoques un error del Sistema Operativo.

Comment: @ChavsoluteLocohombre Aunque depende del compilador y del operativo, lo más habitual es que los literales estén almacenados en una zona de memoria de solo lectura específica para ellos. El puntero apunta a esa zona. En este caso, un intento de modificar la cadena generaría una excepción hardware en tiempo de ejecución que resultaría en un segfault.